# Remote Desktop connection, and browsing locally

Tags: video, flash, remote-desktop, local

Is it possible to "render" (think its the word) Flash and videos like Divx etc on the local machine? so you dont get the lines (they happen quite quick because its connected by ethernet but still annoying) as the screen refreshes down.

Comment: Did Go-to-my-pc work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood it, X-Windows worked this way. The local machine with the keyboard and monitor was the "Server" of said resources, and the remote machine with the big cpu and storage space was the "Client", sending rendering info to the "Server" to be rendered.

This model proved unpopular, as evidenced by the rise of Citrix and Remote Desktop.

You might try Go-to-my-pc. If anyone would have worked out how to split rendering from other tasks, I think Citrix may have done it.

Comment: X still works this way, it's just rarely used over the network.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of Remote Desktop is that you are using the remote machine as if you were sitting at it - so you use it's network connection etc.

There are problems with graphic intensive operations including video and 3D graphics as the rendering is done in software rather than using any hardware acceleration on the local machine. The connection has no direct access to your machine so it can't use the local hardware for rendering.

It does seem odd that you are watching videos via a remote desktop connection. What are you trying to achieve?

**EDIT** There appear a number of pages on how to watch BBC iPlayer videos on the XBox:

http://www.pcpro.co.uk/blogs/2008/11/23/how-to-watch-the-bbc-iplayer-on-the-xbox-360/

http://rory.streetfamily.info/CommentView,guid,f70741eb-898f-470e-9ae2-1f5ac37fba4d.aspx

Though a quick scan would indicate that they're detailing the same solution

Comment: Well I'm not specifically watching videos, just browsing the internet and would like to be able to watch videos like on the BBC site. Without having to be at my computer, but also being able to have access to my desktop, files and programs at the same time.

I'm not 100% sure but the xbox 360 using RDC for its media center, yet streaming videos from things like Sky Player are normal quality and I guess are done on the xbox not the PC.

Comment: @Jonathan - From what I understand the Sky player will be an application that runs on the XBox.

Comment: but it is inside the media center, thanks anyway it's not crucial I can watch videos it would just be better :)